# Colorizing echo works in Solaris but doesn't work in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, colors, solaris

I have 2 different servers where I log in with same network user and run the same script. 
One is Solaris and another is Linux.

Sample echo line from the script works differently on those servers:

```
echo  "\033[1;32mauto update\033[m"
```

In Solaris -> it displays the text "auto update" correctly in green

In Linux -> it displays the text incorrectly and with no color coding: "\033[1;32mauto update\033[m"

.bashrc profile has the following line for PS1:

```
export PS1='${USER}@${HOST%%.*} ${PWD}> '
```

Grateful if you can help me getting the color thing work in Linux.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a good illustration of why `echo` is not considered portable.

On `dash` and Solaris `sh`:

```
echo    "\033[1;32mauto update\033[m"   # Works
echo -e "\033[1;32mauto update\033[m"   # Fails (prints -e)
```

On `bash`, `ash` and `ksh`:

```
echo    "\033[1;32mauto update\033[m"   # Fails (doesn't interpret escapes)
echo -e "\033[1;32mauto update\033[m"   # Works
```

You can instead use `printf`:

```
printf '\033[1;32mauto update\033[m\n'  # Works on all platforms
```